# How to initialize a hammerJS object with options as parameters

Tags: javascript, constructor, hammer.js

So we can create a Hammer object and set change its options like this:

```
let mc = new Hammer(element);

mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_NONE });
```

How can we set the options with the constructor?

This did not work:

```
let mc = new Hammer(element, [{'event' : 'pan', 'direction' : Hammer.DIRECTION_NONE}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
let swiper = new Hammer(element, {'recognizers' : [[Hammer.Pan, {direction : Hammer.DIRECTION_NONE}]]});
```